# This Riley Riddle is open for business!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

My Prefix comes before all others, but why it does, I'm not sure.

My Infix hides those waiting to change their lives.

My Suffix is something made from a plant, without a different plant.

Hint 1:

> The actual infix and the clue for the infix are spelled slightly different. The infix is usually only used on one single day.

Hint 2:

> The prefix is a single letter.

Hint 3:

> The infix can be linked with religion

Hint 4:

> The first plant mentioned in the suffix clue tends to grow large, but the second plant grows small, and is used to make a drink.

Hint 5:

> The "without" part of the suffix clue means that it is the first plant's word, with the letter(s) of the second plant removed.

Comment: A is the prefix and it is super obvious

Comment: @duck then why don't you post an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this Riley riddle

> AVAILABLE?

My Prefix comes before all others, but why it does, I'm not sure.

> Your prefix is A, the first letter which comes before all others.

My Infix hides those waiting to change their lives.

> When she gets married, a bride wears a VEIL; the infix VAIL has a slightly different spelling.

My Suffix is something made from a plant, without a different plant.

> This could be ABLE, but I’m not quite sure why.

Other hint:

> AVAILABLE seems to fit with the clue “open for business” in the title.

Comment: I had the exact same thoughts, curious to see if it's right :)

Comment: that's the right answer, I'll accept it once you figure out why the suffix is what it is. I'll add another hint.

Comment: My instinct: https://www.diynetwork.com/made-and-remade/learn-it/plant-a-beverage-garden